# Can you help me with a flow rate question?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

How many gallons of water (70 degrees F) can flow thru a pipe diameter (I.D. 0.475") at 50 psi over a 30 foot length in a 24 hour time frame?

Comment: try http://www.1728.org/flowrate.htm but do check what they assume the material is... Or https://sciencing.com/convert-psi-gpm-water-8174602.html , you may need this as well : https://www.pipeflowcalculations.com/pressuredrop/index.xhtml

Comment: looks like a duplicate question. https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/8004/4816